# Double comparison problems

Tags: java, comparison, double

I'm writing a pitch detection program in Java and compare two doubles in each iteration of a for loop in order to determine the highest magnitude point in a sample array.

The code for this is:

```
double magnitude = 0.0;
double maxMag = 0.0;

int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2640; i += 2) {
        magnitude = calcMag(sample[i], sample[i + 1])
                * (i < outputLength / 2 ? calcMag(sample[i * 2],
                        sample[i * 2 + 1]) : 1.0)
                * (i < outputLength / 3 ? calcMag(sample[i * 3],
                        sample[i * 3 + 1]) : 1.0)
                * (i < outputLength / 4 ? calcMag(sample[i * 4],
                        sample[i * 4 + 1]) : 1.0)
                * (i < outputLength / 5 ? calcMag(sample[i * 5],
                        sample[i * 5 + 1]) : 1.0);

        if (magnitude > maxMag) {
            maxMag = magnitude;
            peakIndex = j;
        }

        j++;
    }
```

Using a debugger and looking at the variables, the comparison of "magnitude" and "maxMag" works correctly the first time (when maxMag is zero), but from that point on it evaluates to false every time, even when magnitude is in fact greater than maxMag.

Example compared values where (magnitude > maxMag) is false:

magnitude = 2.828262485980501E20

maxMag = 1.3167436120685821E28

I've been looking at this for ages and looked around for potential problems with comparing doubles (I've tried the compare methods of Double to no avail). So now I'm wondering if anyone on here could shed some light on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In your example, `magnitude` is, in fact, smaller than `maxMag`. Notice the "E20" at the end of `magnitude` and "E28" at the end of `maxMag`.

Comment: Your example values *should* have `magnitude > maxMag` be false; magnitude is 2.82*10^20, while maxMag is 1.31*10^28. Don't be fooled by the fact that magnitude starts with a 2, and maxMag starts with 1 - it's using scientific notation, rather than writing out all the digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numbers are written in scientific notation here are there decimal representation breakdown

`2.828262485980501E20 = 2.828262485980501 * 10^20 = 282826248598050100000`

`1.3167436120685821E28 = 1.3167436120685821 * 10^28 = 13167436120685821000000000000`

So

`2.828262485980501E20 < 1.3167436120685821E28`

program output is correct.

Answer (score 1):

but

```
maxMag = 1.3167436120685821E28
```

IS larger than

```
magnitude = 2.828262485980501E20
```

Look at the exponents, after the "E"!

Answer (score 0):

`magnitude` is not greater than `maxMag`.

`magnitude` is in the order of 10 to the 20th power.
`maxMag` is in the order of 10 to the 28th power.

Answer (score 0):

magnitude=2.28e20 is NOT greater than magMax=1.31e28. The integer after E is the exponent. magMax is in fact 1.31 * 10^28 (1 and 28 zeros)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation